# Running apcupsd on server core 2012?

Tags: hyper-v-server-2008-r2, ups, hyper-v-server-2012, apcupsd

Is it possible to run acpupsd on server core 2012?

I went out and bought some Back-UPS (with USB cable signalling) to run some Hyper-V servers before I realized "that wont work" :-)

Back-UPS are not supported by Business Edition, which does support Server Core.
Back-UPS are supported by personal edition, but Personal doesnt seem to support Server Core (it's personal, right?)

So I went out foraging for a open source version and found apcupsd.

Hoping it can run/work on Hyper-V 2012 (which admittedly is not the same as Server Core, but close enough I think?)

UPDATE: So I tried installing 3.14.10 onto a hyper-v 2012 box.  About half way through the install, it tells me it cannot install the USB driver, and to read install.txt in the apcupsd tree.  The Install.txt file talks about using driver manager etc (which of course is not available in core :-)).

I also read something about not being able to install the USB driver on x64 machines.  Am I stuck, or is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2):

To protect the average user, Windows 8(Server 2012) requires all hardware drivers have a digital signature before you can install them, making it more difficult to install malicious drivers.

You can use this driver which worked for me(Hyper-V 2012):
http://eternallybored.org/misc/apcupsd-usb-driver-signed.zip

You can install it with:

```
pnputil -i -a apcupsd.inf
```

Comment: Worked for me in HyperV 2012 R2.  The latest version of apcupsd ships with a signed driver at apcupsd/driver, but I still had to run pnputil on the apcupsd.inf in there.